# aligning C variable declarations in emacs without including * chars

Tags: emacs, alignment

I like using align-current in emacs.  For variable declarations it does this:

```
my_function(
    int         *foo,
    double     **pfoo,
    int          bar)
               ^
1234567890123456
```

(align-to-tab-stop is t, and c-basic-offset is 4)

But I'd prefer the variable names to be aligned to the tab stop, ignoring the pointer `*`'s, like this:

```
my_function(
    int       *foo,
    double   **pfoo,
    int        bar)
               ^
1234567890123456
```

I can't figure out how to change the c-variable-declaration alignment rule to get this.  In my style the `*`'s are always next to the variable name, so it's ok for the solution to work only for that case.  (And actually I want to do this for C++, so I want to ignore both `*`'s and `&'s.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try variation of align-regexp.
M-x align-entire should do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rule text-dollar-figure.  It knows how to align dollar amounts such that the decimal periods line up.  What you want is related, since you want text to fall both left and right of the goal column.

Comment: Thanks -- but it has the same problem.  The c-variable-declaration rule aligns the way I want; it just does not put the goal char in the column I want (ie, at tab stops).